# Python urllib3 and proxy

Tags: python, multithreading, url, proxy, urllib

I am trying to figure out how to use proxy and multithreading.

This code works:

```
requester = urllib3.PoolManager(maxsize = 10, headers = self.headers)
thread_pool = workerpool.WorkerPool()

thread_pool.map(grab_wrapper, [item['link'] for item in products])

thread_pool.shutdown()
thread_pool.wait()
```

Then in `grab_wrapper`

```
requested_page = requester.request('GET', url, assert_same_host = False, headers = self.headers)
```

Headers consist of: Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language and User-Agent

But this does not work in production, since it has to pass proxy, no authorization is required.

I tried different things (passing `proxies` to request, in headers, etc.). The only thing that works is this:

```
requester = urllib3.proxy_from_url(self._PROXY_URL, maxsize = 7, headers = self.headers)
thread_pool = workerpool.WorkerPool(size = 10)

thread_pool.map(grab_wrapper, [item['link'] for item in products])

thread_pool.shutdown()
thread_pool.wait()
```

Now, when I run the program, it will make 10 requests (10 threads) and then... stop. No error, no warning whatsoever. This is the only way I can bypass proxy, but it seems like its not possible to use `proxy_from_url` and `WorkerPool` together.

Any ideas how to combine those two into a working code? I would rather avoid rewriting it into scrappy, etc. due to time limitation

Regards

Comment: Have you tried to create a (proxy) requester per thread (each requester makes requests only from one thread)? Disclaimer: I don't use `urllib3` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are discarding the result of the call to `thread_pool.map()`
Try assigning it to a variable:

```
requester = urllib3.proxy_from_url(PROXY, maxsize=7)
thread_pool = workerpool.WorkerPool(size=10)


def grab_wrapper(url):
    return requester.request('GET', url)


results = thread_pool.map(grab_wrapper, LINKS)

thread_pool.shutdown()
thread_pool.wait()
```

Note:
If you are using a python 3.2 or greater you can use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. It is quote similar to `workerpool` but is included in the standard library.

Comment: Hi, just to verify: thread_pool.shutdown() & thread_pool.wait() should be results.shutdown() & results.wait() right? (results being the object/pointer to the thread_pool instance that was created)

Comment: @Carl: `results` is a *list*/iterable of values, calculated from calling `grab_wrapper()` with each url. So the methods have to be called on `thread_pool`

Answer (score 3):

first of all I would suggest to avoid urllib like the plague and instead use requests, which has really easy support for proxies: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies
Next to that, I haven't use it with multi-threading but with multi-processing and that worked really well, the only thing that you have to figure out is whether you have a dynamic queue or a fairly fixed list that you can spread over workers, an example of the latter which spreads a list of urls evenly over x processes:

```
# *** prepare multi processing
nr_processes = 4
chunksize = int(math.ceil(total_nr_urls / float(nr_processes)))
procs = []
# *** start up processes
for i in range(nr_processes):
    start_row = chunksize * i
    end_row = min(chunksize * (i + 1), total_nr_store)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=url_loop,
            args=(start_row, end_row, str(i), job_id_input))
    procs.append(p)
    p.start()
# *** Wait for all worker processes to finish
for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

every url_loop process writes away its own sets of data to tables in a database, so I don't have to worry about joining it together in python.

Edit: On sharing data between processes ->
For details see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print num.value
    print arr[:]
```

But as you see, basically these special types (Value & Array) enable sharing of data between the processes.
If you instead look for a queue to do a roundrobin like process, you can use JoinableQueue.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I dont think that would cut it. Currently the program has 3 parts: 1. standalone one url processing, 2. multiple url processing (your example would work that), but 3. is a multiple url and data processing where theads share data between them. Can you share data between processes?

Comment: The poster is using urllib*3*, which is in fact the foundation of requests.

Comment: He just mentioned it in his example, not as a solution requirement. Just trying to help out here and imho requests is a lot easier & quicker to implement than any of the urllibs...

Comment: @Carst I didn't want to devalue your solution. Only wanted to point out that he is already quite close to using requests.

Comment: ok, didn't want to sound defensive either! :) to be honest, once I found requests I never looked back at urllib, so i'm not 100% familiar with it! /hides in a corner.
I think your solution is probably more close to what is he asking too. Only thing is that (I think?) you have a typo in it, with thread_pool.shutdown() &wait should be results.shutdown() & wait? (For some reason I cannot comment to your answer...)